# KendoUI chart datasource from grid datasource with JQuery won't render

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid, datasource, kendo-chart

What I am trying to do is dynamically render a chart based on the contents of the KendoUI crid on my page. This is to happen within the DataBound event of the grid. When I try the code below it seems like the space of the gchart is allocated on the page but nothing rnders. I can see through Firebug that the datasource data is in the chart. Also I can see a legend for the chart will render but no chart. I should mention that there is no model passed to this chart. Also I tried hardcoding test data and setiing my datasource to that and still no rendering of the chart.

```
function onDataBound(arg) {
    gridDataSource = arg.sender.dataSource;
    if (gridDataSource.group().length > 0) {

        var theChart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");

        theChart.options.series[0].field = "VALVAL_ALT_CMB_AMT";
        theChart.options.series[0].categoryField = "RCD_NUM";
        theChart.options.series[0].data = gridDataSource._data;
        theChart.refresh();

    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot to add - this is a pie chart

Comment: Since you _hardcoding test data and setiing my datasource to that and still no rendering_ it would be useful for us if you share it. Could you put in JSFiddle or JSBin?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I found the answer to the problem - I could not just set the datasource from the grid to the chart. I needed to first create anew datasource and then set the data property within it to the data from the grid... then setDataSource on the chart and it worked...              var data = new kendo.data.DataSource(
                    {
                        data: gridDataSource._data,

Comment: @burke-holland or a Kendo guy can comment on this further, but I don't believe you should ever reference a property with an underscore ("_"). This syntax is supposed to signal the property/object is a private variable. So something like this might be better: grid.dataSource.view(0); If you are doing something to the data in the grid, maybe this could be incorrect though.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - i was using the names found through Firebugging it. Probably should use the provided names in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem - I could not just set the datasource from the grid to the chart. I needed to first create anew datasource and then set the data property within it to the data from the grid... then setDataSource on the chart and it worked